# BigQuery php client library queryresult shows isComplete false. But I can confirm the query is successful

Tags: google-bigquery

```
$queryResults = $this->bigQuery->runQuery($query, ['parameters' => ['id' => $id]]);

    $info = $queryResults->info();

    var_dump($info);

    // var_dump($queryResults); 

    $isComplete = $queryResults->isComplete();

    if ($isComplete) {
        exit("Insert. Done!");  
    }
```

The query is a "insert select" statement. which I had run successful on bigquery cloud console directly.

When I use php client library here, the query finished successful too and I can confirm that it is the same as I run query directly on google cloud console.

But the info of the query shows isComplete false.

```
array(3) {
["kind"]=>
string(22) "bigquery#queryResponse"
["jobReference"]=>
array(2) {
["projectId"]=>
string(26) "myprojectid"
["jobId"]=>
string(31) "job_OHcckVSSwAI7pHXijmmUqK5H4XE"
}
["jobComplete"]=>
bool(false)
}
```

There are no errors report form the $queryResults->info();. How could I find out why it shows me isComplete false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you still need to run `$queryResults -> reload()` to update the job status. As in the [docs](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.32.1/bigquery/queryresults?method=isComplete):

```
$isComplete = $queryResults->isComplete();

while (!$isComplete) {
    sleep(1); // small delay between requests
    $queryResults->reload();
    $isComplete = $queryResults->isComplete();
}
```